# ListView adapter not getting called through Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

When I call ListViewAdpater through MainActivity it works fine. But if I create ListViewFragment it doesn't get called. I added         `ListViewFragment listViewFragment = new ListViewFragment();` in MainActivity. I have ListViewAdapter as

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] sensorArray) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_adapter, sensorArray);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_adapter, parent, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)  view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
        textView.setText(getItem(position));
        return view;
    }
}
```

But when I call through Fragment as below I don't see any listView

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        String[] sensorArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sensor_array);

        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(),sensorArray));
        return view;
    }
}
```

**When I run debugger it calls ListViewFragment but it doesn't go inside onCreate method**

I changed xml files as below
so in activity_main.xml I added `

```
<fragment  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.app.fragment.ListViewFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/listviewfragment"/>
```

`and created listviewfragment.xml as`'

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

is this right?

Comment: Can you attach code where you are adding ListViewFragment to the activity?

Comment: I added this line in MainActivity `ListViewFragment listViewFragment = new ListViewFragment();` This won't work?

Comment: Nope. I'll add an answer

Comment: You need to inflate the ListView from `onCreateView` of your fragment instead of `R.layout.activity_main` you should be using `R.layout.listviewfragment`

Comment: I changed to R.layout.listviewfragment but now i get java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app/.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
Looks like ListView doesn't like fragments

Comment: No its very common to have a list view in fragment.  Can you paste the full stack trace?

Comment: it worked I have no idea what happened I cleaned and ran it worked! Thanks a lot dude !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments need to be attached to an activity in order to function. You need to add the fragment to the activity using either the xml (statically) or using the fragment manager (dynamically).

Statically you can simply add the fragment by putting this in your activity's layout file:

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.MyFragment"
              android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The `android:name` should point to your fragment class.

Using fragment manager you can add a fragment as follows:
In your activity's onCreate() just use this:

```
    ListViewFragment listViewFragment = new ListViewFragment();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_view, listViewFragment).commit();
```

See [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) and [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) for more details.  You can use `replace` method also with  the container view, which as the name implies will replace the fragment.

Comment: so in activity_main.xml I added `<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.app.fragment.ListViewFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/listviewfragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use FragmentTransaction and must have FrameLayout element in your main activity layout.

activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

MainActivity:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragment_container,new ListViewFragment(), "sensorArray");
ft.commit();
```

Comment: I edited question with xml files bit I get inflateException. Do I need to add id for ListView?

Comment: Try `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout. listviewfragment, container, false);`